# Example of a Group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone come up with an example of a group of order 4 that has no order 4 elements? I have tried a few examples I learned in class but I couldn't come up with this particular one.

Comment: Might I ask what some of the examples were that you tried?

Comment: Hint: There are only two groups of order four.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2.$

$(0,1),(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ have order $2.$ $(0,0)$ is the identity.

Comment: Ah this. Thank you, I can confirm.